# Want to Prevent Oracle External User Domain Displaying the My Apps Page

Tags: oracle

Using a domain external users.

I submit the self registration form and get the message Congratulations you have created your account
a welcome email has been sent for verification
click here to continue
Displays my apps and shows the message you don't have access to any apps

Using my apex app URL and oauth, when I login it displays the application would like to access the profile. I click enable secure verification and select my MFA method
It displays successfully enrolled
I click on done.
it goes to my apps and I get the error message you don't have access to any apps.

The second time I use my apex URL I get the message allow access to the profile, I allow it and then it goes to my apex app as expected.

I would prefer that it doesn't display my apps at all, and instead go to my apex app directly after MFA is set up or forces a new login.

Is that possible?

Comment: You could file a change request with Oracle, but it isn't really possible to change the function of APEX workspace behavior directly.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will come up with plan B.